# Explain difference between opencv's template matching methods in non-mathematical way

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, template-matching

I'm trying to use opencv to find some template in images. While opencv has several template matching methods, I have big trouble to understand the difference and when to use which by looking at their mathematic equization:

- CV_TM_SQDIFF
- CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
- CV_TM_CCORR
- CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED
- CV_TM_CCOEFF

Can someone explain the major difference between all these method in a non-mathematical way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general idea of template matching is to give each location in the target image `I`, a similarity measure, or score, for the given template `T`. The output of this process is the image `R`.

Each element in `R` is computed from the template, which spans over the ranges of `x'` and `y'`, and a window in `I` of the same size.

Now, you have two windows and you want to know how similar they are:

#### CV_TM_SQDIFF - Sum of Square Differences (or SSD):

Simple euclidian distance (squared):

- Take every pair of pixels and subtract
- Square the difference
- Sum all the squares

#### CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED - SSD Normed

This is rarely used in practice, but the normalization part is similar in the next methods.

The nominator term is same as above, but divided by a factor, computed from the 
- square root of the product of:

- sum of the template, squared
- sum of the image window, squared

#### CV_TM_CCORR - Cross Correlation

Basically, this is a dot product:

- Take every pair of pixels and multiply
- Sum all products

#### CV_TM_CCOEFF - Cross Coefficient

Similar to Cross Correlation, but normalized with their Covariances (which I find hard to explain without math. But I would refer to 
[mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficient.html)
or [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html;jsessionid=857698d401f3e77c12feabc11cfb?requestedDomain=true#bunkanr)
for some examples

Comment: awesome explanation. but there is a question: when  CV_TM_CCOEFF "normalized with their Covariance" then why we have (need) CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED ?

Comment: check out this link for good visuals of the different methods:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Comment: From what I see in the [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.10/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d), **CV_TM_CCOEFF** only performs mean centering i.e., the window means of the target and template are subtracted from each pixel in the respective windows. 

The full [normalised variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Zero-normalized_cross-correlation_(ZNCC)) is **CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED**, which does the mean centering and also divides by the standard deviations.